# Facebook login - php sdk - prob

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am in a total mess with facebook-login. The code is given below. You can see the output at http://beta.jokesnfunnypics.com/login. In the scope, I have given as email but when I click the link and is redirected to facebook, it says that the app asks for only the basic permissions. Moreover, I have mentioned the redirect_uri as http://beta.jokesnfunnypics.com/add but I am instead redirected to the same page only. More over again, after getting the permission, no info is being displayed at the page also. Please help me. I am ready to give a few dollars to anyone who gives me the correct code.

```
<?php 
//Application Configurations
$app_id     = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$site_url   = "http://www.beta.jokesnfunnypics.com/add";

try{
        include_once "src/facebook.php";
}catch(Exception $e){
        error_log($e);
}
// Create our application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => $app_id,
'secret'    => $app_secret,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();


if($user){
try{
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
}catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    error_log($e);
    $user = NULL;
}

}

if($user){
    // Get logout URL
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}else{
// Get login URL
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'     => 'email',
    'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
    ));
}


if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>

      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
  <h3>You</h3>
$_SESSION['user']="abc;
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

  <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
  <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
<?php else: ?>
  <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
<?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, don't write your private detail of app secret. It is supposed to be secret

Comment: I am trying the same code as yours and it is working fine. Are you using latest SDK cause your login URL is also not having scope parameter for email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well usually I don't use the php sdk to generate my login url, instead I do it manually, try changing this line:

```
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
```

To this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://beta.jokesnfunnypics.com/add&scope=email">Login with Facebook</a>
```

Comment: But now is already asking for the email, now you have to use the code that is passed as a get parameter to http://beta.jokesnfunnypics.com/add and retrieve the token for the user

Answer (score 1):

From the code, $loginUrl variable is defined 2 times, scope and redirect_uri is missing in the second time . try to remove those lines from your code

```
<?php 
$app_id     = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$site_url   = "http://www.beta.jokesnfunnypics.com/add";

try{
    include_once "src/facebook.php";
 }catch(Exception $e){
   error_log($e);
 }
// Create our application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'     => $app_id,
'secret'    => $app_secret,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){
try{
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
}catch(FacebookApiException $e){
error_log($e);
$user = NULL;
}

}

if($user){
// Get logout URL
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}else{
// Get login URL
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
'scope'     => 'email',
'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
));
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <head>
<title>php-sdk</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>php-sdk</h1>

<?php if ($user): ?>

  <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
  <div>
    Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>PHP Session</h3>
 <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

 <?php if ($user): ?>
  <h3>You</h3>
 $_SESSION['user']="abc";
 <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
 <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
 <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
 <?php else: ?>
 <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
 <?php endif ?>

  <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
  <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Refer these tutorials .

[Login with Facebook using PHP SDK](http://www.idiotminds.com/login-with-facebook-using-php-sdk/)

[Login with facebook using PHP ( Demo and Download )](http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php)